# Ensuring JSON pretty print on simple View Model object that never touches javascript (ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a bit of a mental disconnect. I have seen how to do JSON pretty print [On This Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/json-pretty-print-using-javascript) using `JSON.stringify(obj);` - but I have a situation where I need to do this, but the json never really touches javascript. It is just a string on an MVC view model. It is for an "Error" view, like this ...

( I am using jQuery, if that opens any other options )

## Model

```
public class FailureViewModel{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string JSON { get; set; }
    }
```

It kind of works like this. If the operation fails, it generates the following view.

## Controller

```
        return View("Failure", new FailureViewModel{
            Name = "Some Error Name",
            Message = "There was an error and the changes were not submitted. Please submit this to the administrator",
            JSON = model.ToJson()
        });
```

## View

```
@model FailureViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error With Data Entry";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administrator/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<article>
    <aside class="red">
        @Model.Message
    </aside>
    <aside>
        <pre>
            @Model.JSON
        </pre>
    </aside>
</article>
```

I basically just want to do the "stringify" to the `@Model.JSON` so it shows it all nice and formatted, but I am having trouble doing that without really convoluting the view. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "convoluting the view?"

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999467/how-to-pretty-print-json-script-in-mvc-4-api

Comment: Hey, @charlieftl - I don't know what to do. My solution is (slightly) different from the one you linked, but the one you linked gave me all of the information. 

I'd like to credit you somehow, though.

Answer (score 2):

From the link given to me by @`charlietfl` I have designed the following to accomplish my goal.

### View Model

```
public class SuccessViewModel {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string JSON { get; set; }
    }
```

### Controller

```
    return View("Success", new SuccessViewModel {
        Name = "The Title",
        Message = "The message",
        JSON = model.ToJson()
    });
```

### View

```
@model SuccessViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Successful Data Entry";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administrator/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<article>
    <aside class="green">
        @Model.Message
    </aside>
    <aside>
        <pre id="json-result">
        </pre>
    </aside>
</article>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var str = JSON.stringify(@(new MvcHtmlString(Model.JSON)), undefined, 2); // indentation level = 2
        $('#json-result').html(str);
        console.log(str);
    });
</script>
```

### Extension Method

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows for any object to be serialized into Json very quickly.
/// </summary>
public static class JsonExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to Javascript Object Notation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to serialize.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The item serialized as Json.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ToJson(this object item) {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
    }
}
```